# How to display document list's view using content editor web part via script? SP2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I want to display a document list's view in a other site collection page in SharePoint 2013.

I tried this and couldn't work: [Source from here](http://www.balestra.be/2012/04/want-to-display-a-sharepoint-list-from-another-site-collection-use-these-2-lines-of-jquery-script.html)

Am I doing something wrong or this is not compatible with SP2013?
Please provide an answer that support SharePoint 2013.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If a web part is sufficient, use https://crosssiteviewer.codeplex.com/